# NSTimer with a menu bar app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I'm working on a simple timer app, and I've created a NSStatusItem with a menu and I have some NSTextField labels that updates the timer labels (http://cld.ly/e81dqm) but when I click on the status item the NSTimer stops (and stops updating the labels)..... how can I get around this problem?

**EDIT:** here's the code that starts the timer:

`timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerDidUpdate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: Going to need to see the code where you start and stop the timer. Do you mean that the timer updates the labels?

Comment: and it stops updating when I click on the status item don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the timer resumes as soon as you stop interacting with the NSStatusItem? (After the menu's dismissed & mouse button released).

The user interaction puts the main run loop into a mode where it doesn't update timers, so if your label has to continually update, you'll probably need to move the NSTimer and the label drawing to a separate process or another thread.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to obj-c/cocoa how do I move to another thread etc

Comment: If you haven't done threading before, it's going to take a bit of reading:

Thread Programming Guide: http://tinyurl.com/yjnlegr

Threading & Graphics Contexts: http://tinyurl.com/yflqjjk

A simpler solution might be to set up a delegate for your menu, then implement the menuWillOpen: & menuDidClose: delegate methods to clear the label/view while the menu's open (so at least the user's not seeing an out-of-date label).

Answer (score 11):

You should add timer into MainRunLoop as given below:

```
NSRunLoop * rl = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
[rl addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: This really seems like the preferred answer.

Comment: This seems to be by far the easiest way to do it. Also, you can just do it in one line with `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`